# SwiftUI Buttons in a ScrollView is not tappable sometimes

Tags: swiftui

I have a horizontal ScrollView on top of a MapView.

The ScorllView is a collection of Buttons. It is weird that the buttons in the ScrollView are sometime tapable and sometimes not. First tap always works but after that I have to scroll a bit, tap around different areas in the button, make some secret prayers and then it works!

I tried disabling/removing all other components in the view, but still unable to figure out the root cause.

Has anyone experience this ?

Comment: I've experienced this in Catalyst -- is that where you're seeing this behavior?

Comment: @jnpdx I'm not using Catalyst. This is happening in an iOS only app.

Comment: Can you come up with a [mre]?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I stuck with a same issue with horizontal `ScrollView` on top and `List`. While debugging I added empty `.onTapGesture` to `ScrollView` and it somehow fix my issue.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            Button("one") {}
            Button("two") {}
            Button("three") {}
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture { // <---- fix
    }
    List {
    }
}
```

Comment: You're the man. Just one addition, the tap gesture doesn't need to be an empty one, you can add code as well and it will still work

Comment: Not sure why this works, but it's the only solution that's fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue for Horizontal Scroll view in Swiftui dark theme "CameraTimerItem" buttons not clickable (Problem with dark theme only). Then I put a onTapGesture without any action. It's starts to work normally. I think it's a error of SwiftUI.

```
       VStack (alignment:.center){
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            HStack{
                                ForEach(timeSlots,id: \.self) { item in
                                    CameraTimerItem(cellTitle: item)
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: AppUtils.width, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                           // <---- This is the solution 
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: How is this answer different than Evgeniy Vaganov's answer?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else having this issue, instead of adding an empty .onTapGesture view modifier, check that any HStacks in the ScrollView hierarchy have a `.contentShape(Rectangle())` modifier. By default, HStacks don't accept taps in between their child views, and depending on your child view's layout this can cause taps to be missed even when it looks like they should be landing. `.contentShape(Rectangle())` makes the entire frame of the HStack tappable.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, but the answer of Evgeniy Vaganov did